# Access checkbox through JavaScript and JQuery with their ID

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, checkbox

Despite the facts that I have been searching for almost a week now, I couldn't find a way a way to do what I wanted to, so here I am.
Here's what I want to do: I have a form that should display file names and a checkbox for each name, allowing the user to select which files he wants to choose. Each checkbox's value is the path of the file it's related to, and each checkbox'ID is its file's directory's path plus a number. In my JavaScript, I try to "build" each ID through a loop and then access my checkbox, but I can't make it work, and I'm starting to get a bit desperate; so i hope that you guys can help me. 
Here's my cshtml code:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg ">
<div class="modal-content">
    @{
        string dir = ""+Path.GetDirectoryName(Model);
        var listFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        var nbFiles = listFiles.Count();


    }
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 style="word-wrap:break-word;" class="modal-title">Fichiers contenus dans le répertoire @dir</h4>
        <h3>Nombre de fichiers: @nbFiles</h3>
    </div>

    @{var nb = 0; var idCheck = "";}

    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="frmMoveFile"> 
            @foreach (var file in listFiles)
            {

                idCheck = "check-"+nb+"-"+dir;
                <div style="border:ridge">
                    <p>
                        <b>Fichier</b> : @Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) 

                        <b>Extension :</b> @Path.GetExtension(file)

                        <input class="btn btn-primary"  type="checkbox" id=@idCheck value=@file />
                    </p>
                </div>
                nb++;
            }
        <br />
        <br />
        </form>
        <div class="center">
            @{                                                                            
                var idBtnOk =Model;
            }             
            <button value="@dir" class="btnFrmMove">Déplacer fichiers sélectionnés vers l'outbox</button>
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Supprimer log d'erreur">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btnFrmMove').click(function () {
        var path = $(this).attr("value");
        alert(path);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            var idCheckBox = "check-" + i + "-" + path;
            if ($(idCheckBox).is(":checked")) {
                alert($(idCheckBox).attr("value"));
            }
         }

    })
</script>
```

Am I missing something ? I haven't done a lot of web development until now so it might be a beginner mistake

Comment: I think you are missing double quotes:  id=@idCheck ->  id="@idCheck"

Comment: It doesn't work any better with the double quotes..

Comment: @Timothée Can you print and compare ids you are making in the loop i.e. values of `idCheckBox` and those in the generated html ?

Comment: @Chintan I've already tried that, it gives me the exact same thing. I didn't specified that this view is created a great number of times with different Models, which is why "btnFrmMove" is a class and not and ID, maybe I should have ? Also do you think that the fact there is '\' in my ID might be messing things up ? I've tried to remove them and it didn't change anything, but might it be part of the problem ?

Comment: / is a meta character. It needs to be escaped. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this line of code:

```
$(idCheckBox).is(":checked")
```

You are missing to add the `#` to the `idCheckBox` variable like below:

```
var idCheckBox = "#check-" + i + "-" + path;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I had removed the '#' earlier; but even when I add it doesn't work either..

Comment: `id=@idCheck` and `value=@file`. Are you setting these two attributes in right form? Because I feel that they are missing double quotation as @Groben mentioned. The value should be like `id="..."` and `value="..."`

Comment: yes I've changed it by now, so I have 

    <input class="btn btn-primary"  type="checkbox" id="@idCheck" value="@file" />

it doesnt change anything either

Answer (score 0):

So, as I managed to get access to my checkbox by removing changing their IDs to simpler ones, I think that the problem was coming from the fact that their were special characters in the old ones.